# CSS move one div to another div

Tags: html, css

I have code (**desktop**):

```
<div class="firstDiv">
     <div class="firstDivInside">...</div>
</div>
<div class="secondDiv">
   <div class="secondDivInside">...</div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to move `secondDivInside` to `firstDiv` by using only css ?

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {

}
```

I need (**on phones**):

```
<div class="firstDiv">
     <div class="firstDivInside">...</div>
     <div class="secondDivInside">...</div>
</div>
<div class="secondDiv">
</div>
```

Comment: Depending on your visual styles it might be possible to do (visually). But without styles from you it's hard to answer more detailed.

Comment: No, you can't modify the DOM with CSS. You'll have to do some creative styling or use JavaScript to achieve what you're after.

Comment: Why to do this? you can end the <div class="firstDiv"> at the end and have  it inside the div!

Comment: You can do it with css but it'll never be perfectly done! you may remove the secondDiv class to do it with css but it'll never work as you want!

Comment: @BurhanKashour Coz I have div class on bottom of the page. I wan't to show it on top of page

Comment: If I create hidden div class on top, and I'll show it only on phones. Page speed will change? Sorry for my bad english

Comment: you shouldn't do that, because you have to fill the same content twice... (also google will hate this) pagespeed could also change, because there is more html to load (file is bigger).. take a look at my answer, this should be clean solution for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Is it possible to move secondDivInside to firstDiv by using only css ?*

No...I don't believe there is a way (esoteric or not) to manipulate/shift the actual structure of the DOM with CSS.

The lowest-level, albeit non-elegant, would be to duplicate the div and show/hide it with display:none/block.

However, this seems like a basic structure issue. Why are your elements in ordered in such a way that mobile-reordering must be completely overhauled?

Here is an article that discusses pros/cons of mobile structuring as you design your pages...it's a quick read that may help you better conceptualize how to design for mobile<->desktop. 
https://codemyviews.com/blog/mobilefirst

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is the following :

```
<div class="firstDiv">
     <div class="firstDivInside">...</div>
     <div class="secondDivInsideMobile">...</div>
</div>
<div class="secondDiv">
   <div class="secondDivInside">...</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.secondDivInsideMobile {
   display:none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .secondDivInsideMobile  {
        display:auto;
    }
     .secondDivInside {
        display:none;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant manipulate the DOM with CSS, but you can use `flexbox` to get a layout which will look as your desired markup.

Checkout and play around with this page :)

http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/

Answer (score 1):

You cant manipulate DOM using css, but this could be a solution for you:

```css
.firstDiv {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.secondDiv {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px){
  .secondDiv {
    background: none !important;
    height: unset !important;
    margin-top: unset !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="firstDiv">
  <div class="firstDivInside">...</div>
  <div class="secondDiv">
     <div class="secondDivInside">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> This solution in a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y35wkpgt/

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can't move div using **CSS** but you can show and hide **div** as per viewport. Here is an example, i hope it will help you.

**HTML**

```
<div class="firstDiv">
     <div class="firstDivInside">...</div>
     <div class="secondDivInside">...</div>
</div>
<div class="secondDiv">
   <div class="secondDivInside">...</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.secondDivInside {
   display: none;
}
.secondDiv .secondDivInside {
  display: block;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .secondDivInside {
       display: block;
    }
    .secondDiv {
      display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this with **flexbox**.. with **ORDER**

```
.firstDiv {
display: flex;
}

.firstDivInside {
    order: 1
}

.secondDivInside {
    order: 0
}
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. Could you elaborate how does this achieve te needed code?

Answer (score 0):

1. For the element set `display` to `none` under `@media` ...
2. Run JS script after the element is loaded...
3. Inside the script check the element's `display` with `getComputedStyle()`
4. If it is `none` move the element to the new position with the `insertBefore()`.
5. Set `display` to `block` or whatever for the element.

If one has JS off, he sees nothing, he sees nothing anyway.

```js
if(document.querySelector('.elmToMove')){
    
    if(window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.elmToMove'), null).getPropertyValue("display")=='none'){
        
        if(document.querySelector('.newParent')){ //or any other way to get it

            document.querySelector('.newParent').insertBefore(document.querySelector('.elmToMove'), document.querySelector('.newParent').lastChild.nextSibling);
            
            document.querySelector('.elmToMove').style.setProperty('display','block','important');
        };

    } else{
        document.querySelector('.elmToMove').style.removeProperty('display');
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Really it is not big a problem. This block is really independent and moving of it is us usual in Magento 2 is possible.

Step 1

For layout catalog_category_view.xml do it

```
<move element="catalog.navigation.state" as="navigation_state" destination="product_list_toolbar" before="category.description"/>
```

Step 2. For template Magento_LayeredNavigation::layer/view.phtml

Looking for code like this

```
<?= $block->getChildHtml('state') ?>

        <?php if ($block->getLayer()->getState()->getFilters()): ?>
            <div class="block-actions filter-actions">
                <a id="product-filter-clear"
                   data-pr-filter="clearAll"
                   href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getClearUrl()) ?>"
                   class="action clear filter-clear">
                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Clear All')) ?></span>
                </a>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

And remove it. Because the parent block is trying to use the child's functionality.